# Authorization using Foursquare native iPhone app

Tags: ios, safari, foursquare, url-scheme, authorize

Is there a way Foursquare native iPhone app can handle a url-scheme for authorization without opening the safari browser?

```
foursquare://authorize/app_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not possible as foursquare currently only supports 4 iPhone URLs ([venue, check-in, tip and user](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client#iphone)).